# Difference between {npm --prefix \"RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint} and {npm --prefix functions run lint}?

Tags: node.js, firebase, npm

I was going through this [article](https://medium.com/zero-equals-false/integrating-firebase-cloud-functions-with-google-calendar-api-9a5ac042e869) on "**Integrating Firebase Cloud Functions with Google Calendar API**" and came across the following:

"**If you enabled a linter for your project, we’ll need to make a minor change to the firebase.json file in the root directory.
In the predeploy array, edit the line "**npm --prefix "RESOURCE_DIR" run lint**" to "**npm --prefix functions run lint**". The entirety the file should now be as follows:**"

```
{
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix functions run lint"
    ]
  }
}
```

I wanted to know what "npm --prefix "RESOURCE_DIR" run lint" does and why are we replacing it with "npm --prefix functions run lint"?